# Cross Publishing of SBT Plugins not working

Tags: scala, sbt

My objective is to write an SBT plugin which can be used by SBT 0.13.x and 1.x versions of SBT. Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49516540/not-able-to-cross-publish-my-sbt-plugin-for-multiple-scala-versions) thread and [this](https://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Cross-Build-Plugins.html) documentation. I wrote the following build.sbt for my plugin project

```
lazy val foo = (project in file(".")).settings(
   name := "foo",
   sbtPlugin := true,
   organization := "com.bar",
   version := "1.0.0",
   scalaVersion:= "2.12.4",
   sbtVersion in Global := "1.0.0",
   crossSbtVersions := Seq("0.13.17", "1.0.0"),
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
       "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3"
   ),
   scalaCompilerBridgeSource := {
      val sv = appConfiguration.value.provider.id.version
      ("org.scala-sbt" % "compiler-interface" % sv % "component").sources
   }
)
```

when I do `sbt +publichLocal` I see

```
info] Packaging /Users/user1/IdeaProjects/fulfillment-sbt/target/scala-2.12/sbt-0.13/foo-1.0.0-javadoc.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[info]  published foo to /Users/user1/.ivy2/local/com.bar/foo/scala_2.12/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/poms/foo.pom
[info]  published foo to /Users/user1/.ivy2/local/com.bar/foo/scala_2.12/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/jars/foo.jar
[info]  published foo to /Users/user1/.ivy2/local/com.bar/foo/scala_2.12/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/srcs/foo-sources.jar
[info]  published foo to /Users/user1/.ivy2/local/com.bar/foo/scala_2.12/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/docs/foo-javadoc.jar
[info]  published ivy to /Users/user1/.ivy2/local/com.bar/foo/scala_2.12/sbt_0.13/1.0.0/ivys/ivy.xml
[success] Total time: 9 s, completed Apr 4, 2018 11:12:38 AM
```

But it didn't publish for 1.0 version of SBT. what can I do that it publishes for both versions of SBT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I went to the gitter channel of SBT and had a conversation there with the creators of SBT. Based on that conversation I created a working example. I am listing it here so that it helps someone cross publish sbt plugins in future.

project/build.properties

```
sbt.version=0.13.17
```

build.sbt

```
lazy val p = (project in file(".")).settings(
   name := "sbt-crosspublish",
   sbtPlugin := true,
   organization := "com.abhi",
   version := "1.0.0",
   crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.6", "2.12.0"),   
   crossSbtVersions := Seq("0.13.17", "1.0.0"),
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
       "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3"
   ),
   scalaCompilerBridgeSource := {
      val sv = appConfiguration.value.provider.id.version
      ("org.scala-sbt" % "compiler-interface" % sv % "component").sources
   }
)
```

And finally in order to cross publish SBT plugins one has to do

```
sbt ^publishLocal
```

Wow. didn't know about the `^` the `sbt +publishLocal` is for cross publishing normal binaries not for plugins. for cross publishing of sbt plugins, we must do `sbt ^publishLocal`.

One thing to note is that the `scalaCompilerBridgeSource` thing is only needed if you are working on SBT 0.13.17. If you upgrade to SBT 1.1.0 in the plugin project then the code is simplified.

project/build.properties

```
sbt.version=1.1.2
```

build.sbt

```
lazy val p = (project in file(".")).settings(
   name := "sbt-crosspublish",
   sbtPlugin := true,
   organization := "com.abhi",
   version := "1.0.0",
   crossScalaVersions := Seq("2.10.6", "2.12.0"),   
   crossSbtVersions := Seq("0.13.17", "1.0.0"),
   libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
       "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.3"
   )
)
```